# mod_rewrite redirect sends status code 500

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently using this *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/.]+)/?$ p.php?un=$1 [L]
```

and it works well, its to redirect from

```
p.php?un=2 to profile/Eddy
```

But when i add this to the code to redirect from *brand.php?b=3* to *brand/name*

```
RewriteRule ^brand/([^/.]+)/?$ brand.php?b=$1 [L]
```

It always sends the status/error code 500.

Comment: Did you tried without the `[L]` Flag? It might couses a Problem without rewrite conditions and doesn't seem to be nessecary for your

Comment: Im not getting a 500 Error when tring it on my local machine (only 404 becouse the site doesn't exist) | Whats the `?` for?

Comment: here is the entire hatches file. http://pastebin.com/eMZitTXc

Comment: Perhaps the error is not in the `mod_rewrite`, but in the `brand.php`. Try look `brand.php?b=some-suitable-brand-name`, will it work?

Comment: still no luck. not working

Comment: been trying to find that. please where can i find it

Comment: the last error was on 31st december. 108.175.157.32 - - [31/Dec/2014:19:21:07 -0800] "GET /cron/cron.php HTTP/1.1" 302 218 "-" "lwp-request/5.827 libwww-perl/6.07"

Comment: ok. this has to be it then. [Tue Jan 27 22:12:15 2015] [error] [client 154.120.98.97] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in /home/serviceb/public_html/brand.php on line 45
[Tue Jan 27 22:12:15 2015] [error] [client 154.120.98.97] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1315862 in /home/serviceb/public_html/brand.php on line 48

Comment: just fixed that. and my CPU usage went from 0 - 80% real quick

Comment: waiting for the CPU usage to reduce back to 0.

Comment: the problem still persists. ERROR 500 page

Comment: i think its the apache error log. this is the heading "This function will display the last 300 errors for your site. This can be very useful for finding broken links or problems with missing files. Checking this log frequently can help keep your site running smoothly.

Last 300 Error Log messages in reverse order:". BUT now i can try brand?b=nxtgendesign and it would work, but when i try brand/nxtgendesign it won't work

Comment: this is the last error in it [Tue Jan 27 22:42:02 2015] [error] [client 108.175.157.32] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant offline - assumed 'offline' in /home/serviceb/public_html/include/functions.php on line 56

Comment: if thats not from the apache error log then i have no idea where to find it

Comment: Go into the XAMPP Control Panel and click in the APACHE Line on the button LOGS and there choose Apache error.log

Comment: @eddy Do I understand correctly that all the .htaccess is doing is adding .php, and all the rewriting is actually being done by the php program? Could the loop be: First pass, nothing in .htaccess matches, brand.php maps b=3 to brand/name. No anti-loop protection in .htaccess, so start over. Second pass, brand/name matches .htaccess rule, .htaccess maps it to brand.php?b=name, and brand.php having received an unexpected name rather than the expected number as argument nevertheless tries to be friendly and returns brand/name again. This matches: loop. After many loops, mod_rewrite returns 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try just this much smaller .htaccess:

```
# multiple file types
<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>                   

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54  .php54 .php

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# proc/self/environ? no way!
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} proc/self/environ [OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^ index.php [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/.]+)/?$ p.php?un=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^brand/([^/.]+)/?$ brand.php?b=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Yeah that Looks better :)

Comment: @anubhava Can you explain to me in more detail (I must have take too many stoopid pills this morning:-) how the OP's RewriteRules work (or don't work)? It looks to me like 'profile/Eddy' will get rewritten to 'p.php?un=Eddy'. Where does the '2' in the OP's example come from? And why does the OP's example seem _backward_ to the rewriting actually done? Sorry, but I "just don't get" either the original question or why your solution (which seems to contain among other things the exact same RewriteRules that didn't work for the OP) solved the problem. Teach me to fish, please!

Comment: Actually OP provided .htaccess is this: http://pastebin.com/eMZitTXc and if you compare that with my answer then it will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are several Problems with you .htaccess!
The File shoul start with:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

What are the first 2 Lines of the next part for?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.servicebox.com.ng [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://servicebox.com.ng/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Here should come your Rules From above (probably still not working)

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/.]+)/?$ p.php?un=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^brand/([^/.]+)/?$ brand.php?b=$1 [L]
```

And all the other stuff at the End:

```
# hide .php extension
#To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

#To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

ErrorDocument 400 http://www.servicebox.com.ng/400
#All other ErrorDocuments... and following non related stuff
```

Comment: We will see, he should clean up is htaccess first

Comment: There is still a seccong mod_rewrite and also Change the order of the Rule Blogs in the File